# Continuous path in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ passes through $D^{n}$ finitely many times.

Tags: algebraic-topology, continuity, spheres

I'm facing an algebraic topology exercise, and I only need to prove that in the title to finish it:

Let $f: I \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ a continuous path that passes through the unit sphere $D^{n} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid ||x|| \leq 1\}$ i. e. $f(I) \cap D^{n} \neq \emptyset$. Prove that the path goes inside the sphere only finitely many times.

What I've done so far is this: Since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(B = D^{n} \setminus S^{n-1})$ is an open set, and in this case is also a union of open disjoint intervals $f^{-1}(B) = \bigcup_{\alpha \in L} (a_{\alpha},b_{\alpha})$. I have not found a way to ensure that $L$ es finite.

Intuition tells me it's true, although that's not the actual exercise. Anyone please help me to prove or disprove it. Thanks.

---

Now that I've been proved wrong I would like you to help me with the original excercise:
Let $A$ be a path-connected space and $f: S^{n-1} \to A$ continuous. Let $X = A \cup_{f}
 D^{n} = (A \cup D^{n})/(a \sim f(a))$. Prove that if $n \geq 2$ then the natural mapping $i: A \to X$ induces a surjection on the foundamental groups.

I was trying to get the pre-image over $A$ of every loop in $X$. The only problem of this would be when the loop passes through the disc $D^{n}$ (which is "outside" $A$), but in such case I could deform it and take it to its boundary $S^{n-1}$, which is identified with $A$. This idea was taken from Hatcher's proof of $\Pi_{1}(S^{n}) = 0$, $n \geq 2$. The thing is that he is able to ensure that the loop goes inside the ball only finitely many times, so the homotopy is well-defined. So, given that I am not able to do so, how can I ensure my the homotopy to be well defined?

Comment: I don't think it's true - imagine a graph if $x\sin(1/x)$ but "curved" so that instead of flipping around the line, it flips inside and outside the circle.

Comment: You could probably also construct a counterexample with a [wild arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_arc) where the endpoint (if you include it) lies on the surface of the sphere.

Comment: The falsity of the claim is exactly the reason why it is not easy to prove that topological surfaces ($ 2 $-manifolds without boundary) can be triangulated.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the proposition in question is false: consider the following diagram:

[image]

This is the graph of function $x\sin(1/x)-1$ and it goes inside the sphere (which in this case is a circle) infinitely many times.

Comment: Could you say by which software you graphed such a curve ? Is it Geogebra ?

Comment: @FardadPouran Yes, it's indeed GeoGebra. You can plot functions by simply typing the equation $y=x sin(1/x)$ (or whatever any other function or relation on $x,y$ you want) into the input box

Answer (score 0):

See page 35 of Hatcher's Algebraic topology book. It is freely available on his homepage: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html The proof of proposition 1.14 is probably exactly what you want, so I am not going to repeat it here.